# connecting parse api to android swipe layout

Tags: java, android, listview, android-fragments

I'm doing a project using Android swipe layout. I'm getting problem when calling a datas from parse server to swiped tabs.

I'm getting this error when I'm calling a list fragment inside a fragment 
below is my fragment class
 please check

i updated code but  some errors showing  please check below screenshot

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0uExX.png)

[this error comes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HQEKB.png)

```
import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.app.ListFragment;
import android.database.DataSetObserver;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ListAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import com.parse.FindCallback;
import com.parse.ParseException;
import com.parse.ParseObject;
import com.parse.ParseQuery;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;



public class IndividualsFragment extends ListFragment implements FindCallback<ParseObject> {

private List<ParseObject> mOrganization = new ArrayList<ParseObject>();

@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle b) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, b);

        CustomAdaptor adaptor = new CustomAdaptor(getActivity(), mOrganization);
        setListAdapter(adaptor);

        // This is like calling fetchList()
        ParseQuery.getQuery("Organization").findInBackground(this);
        }

/**
 * This is needed by implementing the callback on the class
 **/
@Override
public void done(List<ParseObject> scoreList, ParseException e) {
        if (e == null) {
        Log.d("score", "Retrieved " + scoreList.size() + " Organization");
        mOrganization.clear();
        mOrganization.addAll(scoreList);

        getListAdapter().notifyDataSetChanged();
        } else {
        Log.d("score", "Error: " + e.getMessage());
        }
        }
        }
```

MainActivity.class

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    /**
     * The {@link android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter} that will provide
     * fragments for each of the sections. We use a
     * {@link FragmentPagerAdapter} derivative, which will keep every
     * loaded fragment in memory. If this becomes too memory intensive, it
     * may be best to switch to a
     * {@link android.support.v4.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter}.
     */
    private SectionsPagerAdapter mSectionsPagerAdapter;

    /**
     * The {@link ViewPager} that will host the section contents.
     */
    private ViewPager mViewPager;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        // Create the adapter that will return a fragment for each of the three
        // primary sections of the activity.
        mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

        // Set up the ViewPager with the sections adapter.
        mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.container);
        mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);

        TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(mViewPager);

       Parse.initialize(new Parse.Configuration.Builder(this)
            .applicationId("my-app-id")
            .server("severn-name")
            .build()
        );
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

        public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {

            Fragment fragment = null;

            switch (position) {
                case 0:
                    Individuals t1 = new Individuals();
                    return t1;
                case 1:
                    Events t2 = new Events();
                    return t2;
                case 2:
                    Members t3 = new Members();
                    return t3;
            }
            return fragment;  
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            // Show 3 total pages.
            return 3;
        }

        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
            switch (position) {
                case 0:
                    return "INdividuals";
                case 1:
                    return "Events";
                case 2:
                    return "Members";
            }
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

This is where I call parse data.

OrganizationActivity.class

```
public class OrganizationActivity extends ListActivity {

    protected List<ParseObject> mOrganization;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_organization);
        fetcAndList();
    }

    void fetcAndList() {
    ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("Organization");
    query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {
            public void done(List<ParseObject> scoreList, ParseException e) {
                if (e == null) {
                    Log.d("score", "Retrieved " + scoreList.size() + " Organization");
                    mOrganization = scoreList;
                    CustomAdaptor adaptor = new CustomAdaptor(getListView().getContext(), mOrganization);
                    setListAdapter(adaptor);
                } else {
                    Log.d("score", "Error: " + e.getMessage());
                }
            }
        });
    }

    public void onCreate() {  }
}
```

This is tab1

Individuals.java

```
      import android.database.DataSetObserver;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
    import android.util.Log;
    import android.view.LayoutInflater;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.ViewGroup;
    import android.widget.ListAdapter;
    import android.widget.ListView;

    import com.parse.FindCallback;
    import com.parse.ParseException;
    import com.parse.ParseObject;
    import com.parse.ParseQuery;

    import java.util.List;

    /**
     * Created by faizal on 1/17/17.
     */

    public class Individuals extends Fragment implements ListAdapter  {

public class IndividualsActivity extends Fragment {
    ListView listview;



     public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


        OrganizationActivity.fetcAndList();
    }




    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {



        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_organization, container, false);
        listview = (ListView)v.findViewById(R.id.list);



        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


        return v;

    }


    }
```

I have created 5 xml files. This was automatically created when creating the Android Studio project.

**activity_main.xml**

This is list view xml

activity_organization.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin">

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/list"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true">        
        </ListView>        

    </LinearLayout>
```

This is tab1.xml
This is the first tab , here I call the fields of list view.

**t1.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="cmcom.com.fbcapp.swipe_new.MainActivity$PlaceholderFragment">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/logo"
        android:layout_gravity="left"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
        android:paddingEnd="5dp"
        android:paddingBottom="5dp"
        android:paddingRight="5dp"
        android:paddingStart="5dp"
        android:paddingTop="5dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="12dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="12dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="14dp">    
    </ImageView>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/name"
        android:text="Name"
        android:layout_width="204dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/user"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/user"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/user"
        android:layout_marginTop="13dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/user"
        android:text="Username"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="17dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="17dp"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/logo"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/logo"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/logo" />
 </RelativeLayout>
```

I tried many times but failed to load parse data inside the tab fragments 
if anyone know please help me thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your ListView is not at all attached to the swipe views. Plus, it's an activity. You need to swipe between Fragments. So move the Parse code into a Fragment with a ListView

And a Fragment is not an Adapter, so you need to implement nothing

```
public class Individuals extends Fragment { // No implements needed 
    // Code
}
```

Then `setAdapter` is not a method of the `Fragment` class, so you have to use the method of the ListView itself or use a `ListFragment`

Here's an example of a `ListFragment`

(code untested)

```
public class IndividualsFragment 
  extends android.support.v4.app.ListFragment 
  implements FindCallback<ParseObject> {

    private List<ParseObject> mOrganization = new ArrayList<ParseObject>();

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle b) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, b);

        CustomAdaptor adaptor = new CustomAdaptor(getActivity(), mOrganization);
        setListAdapter(adaptor);

        // This is like calling fetchList()
        ParseQuery.getQuery("Organization").findInBackground(this);
    }

    /**
    * This is needed by implementing the callback on the class
    **/
    @Override
    public void done(List<ParseObject> scoreList, ParseException e) {
        if (e == null) {
            Log.d("score", "Retrieved " + scoreList.size() + " Organization");
            mOrganization.clear();
            mOrganization.addAll(scoreList);

            ((CustomAdaptor) getListAdapter()).notifyDataSetChanged();
        } else {
            Log.d("score", "Error: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: hi @cricket_007 thanks for the reply  . i change the android:id="@android:id/list   can you please tell me which code i need to move to fragment ?

Comment: thanks for reply  yes on the first tab i need to display the list view can you please tell the code which i need to put in order to display list view

Comment: hi @ cricket_007 thanks ,  can you please help with the code because I don't know which code to put

Comment: You already have the code, so, yes you do know which code. There's a ListView in the OrganizationActivity. There is no listview in any of your Fragments. So, as I'm going to say again, move the ListView into a Fragment

Comment: hi  @cricket_007 thanks ,  i put listview inside  Individuals.java still not working .can you please check

Comment: hi , @cricket_007 .. thanks for the reply . I moved the listview  inside Individuals.java    fragment file but still not working . i think i have made mistake . can you check please                               i

Comment: I told you to move the **ListView** not the **entire Activity class**,  which you don't even need from what I understand. Please try to create a [mcve] of a ListView Fragment in a completely new project from the beginning. Forget the swipe views. You need to learn how Fragments work

Comment: thanks @ cricket_007 thanks for the reply . I try it

Comment: @Faizal regarding your latest edits, for a List fragment, instead of onCreate method like Activities, you should use onViewCreated because 1) that's what your error says "no content view" 2) Fragments typically use onCreateView instead of onCreate, but since you have a List fragment, you don't need a custom XML layout

Comment: thanks @cricket_007  for the reply. i'll use onCreateView and try

Comment: thank you for help.  I tried using the code you provided there is an error showing in my parse code

Comment: @FaizalMohamed See how I have `IndividualsFragment extends ListFragment`? And I only have a total of two methods? Why do you have `implements ListAdapter`? Why do you have so many methods? If your ListView is in the first tab, the `Individuals` class, then why are you trying to use `OrganizationActivity`?

Comment: thanks for the quick response .. my mistake I'm sorry . i tried your code but some methods not available in it thats y i tried getting getters and setters  .. now I have used your code n i put screen shot of my error message ..

Comment: thanks .. i tried it but one method not supported i put screenshot please check

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42968587/android-email-client-receiver-email-id-empty-in-android-parse   @cricket_007  hi please check if you can thank you

Answer (score 0):

you may need to call back listview in
OrganizationActivity.class

Comment: thank you for the reply ..can you please tell which code i need to put in OrganizationActivity.class ?

Comment: ListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);

Comment: hi, Fahad Shah thanks for the code help ,  now i changed as your code  , now no error is i but not working can you please help                                                                                                                            protected List<ParseObject> mOrganization;
    ListView mlistt;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
         mlistt = ( ListView ) findViewById(R.id.list);
        fetcAndList();
    }